# OAuth Google Analytics Authentication with PHP

Tags: php, oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get OAuth to work with Google Analytics, but I'm not having any luck. My code looks like this:

```
require_once('common.inc.php');

$consumerKey = "my.url.net";
$consumerSecret = "nzZ....TX";
$sig_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
$oauth_token = $token ? new OAuthToken($token, $token_secret) : NULL;
$token_endpoint = '/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken';
$scope = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/';
$callback_url = "http://my.url.net/pete/oauth/";
$privKey = NULL;
$params = array('scope' => $scope, 'oauth_callback' => $callback_url);
$url = $token_endpoint . '?scope=' . urlencode($scope);

$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

$req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $oauth_token, 'GET',
                                             $url, $params);

//$req->sign_request($sig_method, $consumer, $oauth_token, NULL);

echo "<PRE>";
print_r($req);

// Fill response
echo json_encode(array(
    'html_link' => '',
    'base_string' =>  $req->get_signature_base_string(),
    'response' => send_signed_request('GET', $url, array($req->to_header())),
    'authorization_header' => $req->to_header()
));
```

So when this code runs it prints this:

```
OAuthRequest Object
(
    [parameters:OAuthRequest:private] => Array
        (
            [oauth_version] => 1.0
            [oauth_nonce] => 5f....11
            [oauth_timestamp] => 1306433873
            [oauth_consumer_key] => my.url.net
            [scope] => https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/
            [oauth_callback] => http://my.url.net/pete/oauth/
        )

    [http_method:OAuthRequest:private] => GET
    [http_url:OAuthRequest:private] => /accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Ffeeds%2F
    [base_string] => 
)
```

When I uncomment this line:

```
//$req->sign_request($sig_method, $consumer, $oauth_token, NULL);
```

The script just fails to load showing Server Error. What am I doing wrong? Any advice would help, thanks!

Comment: Presumably "Server Error" is a "500 Internal Server Error". Check the server's error log for exact details as to what's causing it. The stuff you see in the browser is utterly useless for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment Mark, this was actually because my "$sig_method" variable was actually just a string containing "HMAC..." when it actually needed to be an object called this:

```
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!